# wrong time using Gedmo Bundle

Tags: symfony, bundle

Im using Gedmo bundle to save automatically the time in two rows "created_at" and "updated_at",all works fine but it save the data with a wrong time,for example when I save  something in 2:00 pm I find it put 4:00pm in database...its very weird...

Comment: could be your php.ini settings

Answer (score 1):

Locate the php.ini file on your machine

in my machine file located at "/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini"

Find the line with ;date.timezone = under the [Date] section, and set it to your timezone based on [PHP's list of timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

I chose Asia/Kolkata because i lived there. Also, make sure to remove the semicolon at the beginning of the line!

Don't forget to restart apache -  **sudo service apache2 restart**

Comment: ok it's great I'm ok with your solution,but I have the same problem on remote server,I'm using OVH and I can't see any php.ini in?

Answer (score 0):

Change timezone using below php function.

```
date_default_timezone_set('YourTimeZone');
```

For more detail refer : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php